# Is there a word for describing a person who experiences schadenfreude?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

One word to denote a person who derives pleasure from another's misfortune?

Comment: Not sure if [sadist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sadist) could work in this context but it is close.

Comment: A sadist is active and possibly the perpetrator of the misfortune. He is not passive like someone enjoying watching people's misfurtunes

Comment: I like "[sociopath](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sociopathic?show=0&t=1360306467)" in this case. "Barbarian" and "troglodyte" also work.

Comment: @Bill - but while a person enjoying schadenfreude may be any of those, none of them tells us that the active word was schadenfreude

Comment: If you can get the adverb of _epichairekakia_, perhaps you succeeded :)

Comment: @mplungjan: True enough, but it doesn't have to, does it? I suppose we could coin "schadenfreudean" and maybe even "schadenjungian" and "schadenmarxian". :-)

Comment: hehe... adlerian

Comment: Just putting it out there - *schadenfreuder*?

Answer (score 6):

**Gloater**:
One who feels or expresses triumphant and malicious satisfaction at another's misfortune.

Comment: I don't think gloating relates to satisfaction at another's misfortune.  It relates to the overt show of superiority over the loser when they've 'won' or proven the 'loser' wrong.

Comment: From wikipedia: Gloating is differentiated from Schadenfreude in that it does not necessarily require malice (one may gloat to a friend about having defeated him in a game without ill intent) and that it describes an action rather than a state of mind (one typically gloats to the subject of the misfortune or to a third party).

Answer (score 0):

**Sadist:** One who derives pleasure through cruelty or pain to others.

The literal definition has a strong physical connotation to it, but the term does often get used loosely.

Comment: A sadist is actively inflicting cruelty. Someone gloating over other's misfortune is likely passively doing so

Comment: You're referring to the literal definition. I offered and qualified my answer as useful as used more loosely (which the word often is, at least in the states).

Comment: +1, [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sadist),2: *delight in cruelty*.  No mention of who's doing it or how.

Answer (score 0):

The a word *[schadenfreude](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreude)* borrows from the German *Schadenfreude* (“joy in the misfortune of others”).

There is also a rare word *[schadenfreuder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreuder)*, a person experiencing schadenfreude.